# Comma - time agreement

Tags: grammar, commas

Is this correct to express that he cannot 7-10:15 and at other time he can, please? Or should be "otherwise whenever" separated by a comma.

> He does not have time between 7:00 and 10:15, otherwise whenever on Sunday.

or is it better

> Apart from (except for/excluding) 7:00 - 10:15, he has time all Sunday.

> He has time all Sunday but 7:00 - 10:15.

?

Comment: Unrelated to time, the word *otherwise* usually calls for a comma, for a small pause as it introduces contrast.

Comment: Thank you. So, is this sentence correct? "He cannot between 7:00 and 10:15, otherwise whenever on Sunday."

Comment: It's a sentence fragment (or several), not a sentence ... there's no main verb.

Comment: Thank you I edited the options. Now, please?